# Extending/Modifying OpenIso8583.Net

Tags: customization, iso8583, openiso8583.net

I'm using the excellent [OpenIso8583Net](http://code.google.com/p/openiso8583net/) to send/receive ISO messages. However, since every  organization has its own definition and customization, I want to be able to customoize the format with as little touch to the projects' source as possible to be able to upgrade to new versions more easily.
So here are three customizations I am facing right now:

- How can I make `Bitmap` to use `AsciiFormatter` instead of `BinaryFormatter`?  since bitmap is a private field of `AMessage` class, I cannot access it even if I directly derive a new custom class from `AMessage`. And the constructor uses `BinaryFormatter` by default. Currently, I have modified Bitmap.cs parameterless constructor to use `AsciiFormatter`.
- Same story goes for variable length formatter. It uses `AsciiFormatter` by default. But I'd like it to use `BcdFormatter`. I have Modified this part to use `BcdFormatter` by default in VariableLengthFormatter.
  I'd appreciate if anyone shows me a better way to handle these customizations by extending, not modifying.
- Suppose I want to display fields in a log file. An example would be what I have displayed at [Generating MAC by encrypting data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9261526/337294) in the `Fields` section. Right now, I have to make `Template` property public and use the following snippet:  


  for (var i = 2; i

How can I access the fields without making the `Template` public? I want to access the `Display` method of fields in my main program for logging purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have just made changes to the project to allow this.  As of version 0.5.0 (Update your NuGet package)

## Bitmap Formatter

You can set the bitmap formatter in the Template for your message class.  Here is some sample code:

```
public class AsciiIsoMsg : Iso8583
{
    // First you need to customise the template
    // The message 
    private static readonly Template template;

    static AsciiIsoMsg()
    {
        // Get the default template for the Iso8583 class
        template = GetDefaultIso8583Template();
        // change the bitmap formatter
        template.BitmapFormatter = new AsciiFormatter();
    }

    // override the base class using the template and you will be using the bitmap formatter
    public AsciiIsoMsg():base(template)
    {

    }
}
```

## Set Length Formatter of a field

In the `static AsciiIso()` method, if you modify in this manner, you'll change field 2 to use a BCD length formatter:

```
// Set field 2 to use BCD formatter
template[2] = FieldDescriptor.BcdVar(2, 19, Formatters.Bcd);
```

## Log File

To display the message in the log file, use the `.ToString()` method on the message class, e.g.

```
var msg = new AsciiIsoMsg();
msg.MessageType = Iso8583.MsgType._0200_TRAN_REQ;
msg[3] = "010000";
Console.WriteLine(msg.ToString());
```

Which gives:

```
0200:
   [Fixed    n         6 0006] 003 [010000]
```

Comment: Just noticed the `LengthFormatter` of FieldDescriptor has no setter. I have manually added the setter until you update the source. Thanks.